# Uploading Image issue in Alamofire

Tags: ios, image, alamofire

this is my first try while uploading a single image through Alamofire to the server. I have searched for it and got one method to do it. This is how i'm passing image from my imageview to the parameter of my API.

```
 // import Alamofire
func uploadWithAlamofire() {

    let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token")
    let image = UIImage(cgImage: profileImage.image as! CGImage)
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    // define parameters
    let parameters = [
        "token" : token!,
        "name" : nameTxt.text!,
        "about" : descriptionTxt.text!,
        "picture" : imageData as Any
    ] as [String : Any]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) {
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }

        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(((value as AnyObject).data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
        }}, to: "upload_url", method: .post, headers: ["Authorization": "auth_token"],
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.response { [weak self] response in
                        guard let strongSelf = self else {
                            return
                        }
                        debugPrint(response)
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print("error:\(encodingError)")
                }
    })
}
```

I'm getting issue in this line of code,`multipartFormData.append(((value as AnyObject).data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)` The error that compiler is showing is this, ``Type 'UInt' has no member 'utf8'` . How can i resolve this? and is this the right way to send image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the image from params and append it in multipart only

- "picture" : imageData as Any (remove this)
- multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png") (Rename your picture param here and insert image)

Comment: How i should rename the picture param here? @Chanpreet Singh

Comment: withName is your param name i.e- picture and filename you can write anything

Comment: The app is crashing at this line of code, let image = UIImage(cgImage: profileImage.image as! CGImage) with this error, Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) . @Chanpreet Singh

Comment: If profile image is your image view then just pick the image from it and pass to alamofire

Comment: Your conversion for UIImage might be returning nil

Comment: When i run the code it is showing this, (Request) <NSURLRequest: 0x6000002006c0> { URL: http://softdepth.com/projects/raven/customer/update_profile }
(Response) (null)
(Fetch Start) 2018-08-28 06:54:04 +0000
(Domain Lookup Start) 2018-08-28 06:54:04 +0000. The API status code is 200 but is shows this in console. @Chanpreet Singh

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function and its working fine. Give it a try.

```
func postImageToDB(image : UIImage) {
                           **//enter your url here** 
    let imagePostUrlStr =  "https://myWebsiteName.com/upload_image.php/"

    guard let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else {
      return
    }
    //want to save my image to this directory which is inside root
    **//your params may be different.**
    let params = ["path" : "Brainplow/001243192018125835"]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multiPartFormData: MultipartFormData) in
      //append path parameter
      for (key, value) in params {
        multiPartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
      }
      multiPartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "fileToUpload", fileName: "testfilename.png", mimeType: "image/png")

    }, to: imagePostUrlStr) { (result: SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult) in
      switch result {
      case .success(request: let uploadRequest, _, _ ):


        uploadRequest.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

          print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")

        })

        uploadRequest.responseString { response in
          print("printing response string")
          print(response.value as Any)
          print(response)
          print(response.result)

        }

      case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }


  }
```

Comment: where will this name be given? fileName: "testfilename.png". Is it your image name or just any random name? @Awais Fayyaz

Comment: I have tried with ur code but its is showing me only Upload Progress and some digits in front of that. @Awais Fayyaz

Comment: `testfilename.png` is random name

Comment: what is your response type? in my case, it was string. so i used `uploadRequest.responseString` with completion handler.